# Do I need to send ESC commands through a windows driver?

Tags: vb.net, printing

Can anyone help me.

Do I need to send printer commands when printing through a windows driver?
I am writing a windows forms application which prints out information on a label printer. This information contains an image which has a title and a barcode on it. I can create the image ok, but when I try to send it to the printer it prints completely wrong!

Answer (score 0):

The Esc commands are normally handled through the Windows Driver. Here's rough example on how to print an image. You initialize PrintDocument, then use the Print method to start printing. Windows then calls the PrintPage handler, which draws on e.Graphics. e.Graphics is effectively the printer page.

```
Dim pd As PrintDocument
AddHandler pd.PrintPage, AddressOf printPage
' assign pd properties
pd.Print

Sub printPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)
' assign img, set rectangle, determine number of pages, etc.
e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, rectangle)  ' essentially draws on the printer page
e.HasMorePages = ...
end sub
```